# mod_rewrite inserting full path to file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create a rewrite to take traffic going to mp3/mp4 files in a specific subdirectory and then route them to a PHP file that tracks download stats etc before routing them to the actual file location since iTunes requires your podcast RSS contain actual media file extensions (.mp3, .mp4, etc)

I have created rewrites before with no problem but now I am running into an odd issue on this company's server.

My .htaccess located at www.company.com/companytools/podcasts

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*).mp3$ /test.php?file=$1 [r=301,L]
```

Right now it is partially working it does act upon the mp3 file but ends up including the full path to test.php after the domain, so I end up with a 404 page looking for this URL:

www.company.com/www/internal/docs/companytools/podcasts/test.php?file=test

basically I need the path, but only the /companytools/podcasts part.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need `R=301` here to hide actual PHP handler.

Try this rule with `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /companytools/podcasts/

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.mp3$ test.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```